# How works glm::quatLookAt?

Tags: c++, glm-math

How does `glm::quatLookAt` works? It make not any sense to me.
I am struggling with glm for hours and the documentation of GLM is very bad. The documentation has concept of "forward vector" without any more details.
For example, `quatLookAt({1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0})` does not make a rotation that direction is `(1, 0, 0)`, but `(0, 0, 1)`:

[image]

How does that work?

Comment: Forward direction all across OpenGL is -Z direction. So by applying the returned quaternion to -Z you arrive at X

Comment: I figured out watching again the figure... thanks